# Comparing two inputs with database data: error

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to compare two input values with two values from a SAME ROW, from a MySQL table.
But I always get an error message. What is wrong in this code? (It worked fine with just one input)

```
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); 
}


// escape variables for security

$numero_cedula = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['numero_cedula']);
$codigo= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['codigo']);


$sql1 = " SELECT Numero Cedula   FROM Teste   WHERE Numero Cedula=$numero_cedula
  AND Chave=$codigo";

$objGet = mysqli_query($con, $sql1);


if( mysqli_num_rows($objGet) > 0 ) {
echo "Duplicate";  
} else {
 echo "Not a duplicate";
}
```

Comment: @getlost , it's an error that has always meant that I have a  syntax error in my code. More specifically: 

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: @manuelmourato Consult [**my answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26435995/1415724) below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although spaces in column names are allowed in SQL, the reason for this (*in your case*) is because the column name `Numero Cedula` contains a space:

```
                      v -- space                     v -- space
$sql1 = "SELECT Numero Cedula FROM Teste WHERE Numero Cedula=$numero_cedula
  AND Chave=$codigo";
```

Change it to the following while wrapping the column name in backticks:

```
$sql1 = "SELECT `Numero Cedula` FROM Teste WHERE `Numero Cedula`=$numero_cedula
  AND Chave=$codigo";
```

Plus, make sure that both `$numero_cedula` and `$codigo` are integers, and that your columns are also `int` types.

If they are not, then both will need to be wrapped in quotes.

I.e.:

```
$sql1 = "SELECT `Numero Cedula` FROM Teste WHERE `Numero Cedula`='$numero_cedula'
  AND Chave='$codigo'";
```

Add `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()` which will show you the error in SQL.

- You can also rename the column in your database to `Numero_Cedula` using an underscore.

***Sidenote:***

You wrote: *"It worked fine with just one input"*.

You will need to elaborate on that and whether your table contains two seperate columns such as `Numero` **and** `Cedula` or one `Numero Cedula`.

---

However, using this method is subject to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

---

***An insight:***

Also make sure that your form elements are named.

I.e.: `name="numero_cedula"` and `name="codigo"`

Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never for production.

Answer (score 0):

You have created a column name with space. So in SQL it will consider only Numero as a column name. What you can do is. Enclose your column name with a back quote ( ` ). Or remove space from column name.

Hope this helps you. :)